# MissingTemplate : Render partial in Rails 3.2.3

Tags: render, ruby-on-rails-3.2, actionview, partials, missing-template

Hi I am new to Ruby on Rails and I am following Michael Hartl's book online.
In [Partials](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/filling-in-the-layout#code%3alayout_with_partials) section of his book. The code he used to render partial was

```
<%= render 'layouts/stylesheets' %>
```

but I get this [error](http://geekpics.net/images/2012/05/30/Bq1bs.png).

I read the API and tried this

```
<%=render :partial => "/layouts/stylesheets" %>
```

but still can't figure this one out.

Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I overlooked the filename. When I initially created the file, after the .erb extension, I accidentally put a space after.

Comment: You should give credit to the person that helped you (and probably others) and provided THE correct answer.

Answer (score 5):

In your view, make sure you have the following structure:

```
- views
  - layouts
    - application.html.erb
    - _stylesheets.html.erb
```

Your code should be:

```
<%= render 'layouts/stylesheets' %>
```

If your main template is inside the layouts folder:

```
<%= render 'stylesheets' %>
```

Comment: When I remove the path before stylesheets, i get this error Missing partial pages/stylesheets, application/stylesheets with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee]}.

Comment: Thanks for the response I finally solved it! It was caused by a simple mispelled file. :(

Comment: Rails searches for partials in views... so, as far as I know, if you have your partials inside layouts, you always need to tell him to look inside that directory. I might be wrong...